# Using Firebase Cloud Messaging + React and firebase.messaging().getToken() is different each refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, gatsby

I'm building a React web app on Gatsby and I'm trying to incorporate push notifications using FCM. I have the firebase-messaging-sw.js service worker in place and I am trying to get a token by this method in my app:

```js
messaging
  .requestPermission()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Permission received.');                
    return messaging.getToken();
  })
  .then(token => {
    console.log(token);                
    // Save token with user.
    return this.saveFcmToken(token, authUser);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error occurred.', error);
  });
```

I call this snippet inside a firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged() to get the user.

The problem is I get a different token each time. I haven't seen this type of issue documented after extended search.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was down to https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9770

In develop mode, Gatsby apparently unregisters service workers. Using a production build got rid of the problem.